# Error Loading Design when using module inside generate block

Tags: verilog, hdl, modelsim

I have the following modules in separate files. When I try to run my `RC_ADD_SUB_32` module, I get the error

> Instantiation of 'inst' failed. Region:
> /RC_ADD_SUB_32_TB/obj/rc_gen_loop[0]/FULL_ADDER The design unit was
> not found. Error loading Design.

Instantiating the Full Adder does not work inside the `generate` block. I'm having trouble instantiating The Full Adder in the `rc_add_sub_32.v` file. Any ideas?

full_adder.v

```
module FULL_ADDER(S,CO,A,B, CI);
    output S,CO;
    input A,B, CI;

    wire HF_1_Y, HF_1_C, HF_2_C; //Half Adder 1 Y, Half Adder 1 C and Half Adder 2 C

    HALF_ADDER inst_01 (.A(A), .B(B), .Y(HF_1_Y), .C(HF_1_C));
    HALF_ADDER inst_02 (.A(HF_1_Y), .B(CI), .Y(S), .C(HF_2_C));
    or inst_03(CO, HF_2_C, HF_1_C);
endmodule;
```

rc_add_sub_32.v

```
module RC_ADD_SUB_32(Y, CO, A, B, SnA);
    // output list
    //output [63:0] Y;
    output [`DATA_INDEX_LIMIT:0] Y; //Our result
    output CO; 
    // input list
    //input [63:0] A;
    //input [63:0] B;
    input [`DATA_INDEX_LIMIT:0] A;
    input [`DATA_INDEX_LIMIT:0] B;

    input SnA;

    //full adder -> full adder connection
    wire [`DATA_INDEX_LIMIT:0] CO_TO_CI;
    wire [`DATA_INDEX_LIMIT:0] XOR_OUT;

    genvar i;
    generate
        for(i=0; i<32; i=i+1)
        begin: rc_gen_loop
        /*
            Cases:
            Index 0: CI is SnA  CO -> CI[1]
            Index 31: CI is CO from index 30, CO is output CO,
            Index 1-30: CI is from previous CO, CO points to next CI
        */ 
            xor xors(XOR_OUT[i], SnA, B[i]);
            if(i==0) 
            begin: 
                FULL_ADDER inst(.S(Y[i]), .CO(CO_TO_CI[i]), .A(A[i]), .B(XOR_OUT[i]), .CI(SnA));
            end
            else if(i==31) 
            begin:
                FULL_ADDER inst(.S(Y[i]), .CO(CO), .A(A[i]), .B(XOR_OUT[i]), .CI(CO_TO_CI[i-1]));
            end
            else if(i!=31 && i!=0) 
            begin:
                FULL_ADDER inst(.S(Y[i]), .CO(CO_TO_CI[i]), .A(A[i]), .B(XOR_OUT[i]), .CI(CO_TO_CI[i-1]));
            end
        end
    endgenerate
endmodule
```

The testbench file rc_add_sub_tb.v

```
module RC_ADD_SUB_32_TB;
    reg [`DATA_INDEX_LIMIT:0] A;
    reg [`DATA_INDEX_LIMIT:0] B;
    reg SnA;

    wire [`DATA_INDEX_LIMIT:0] Y;
    wire CO;

    RC_ADD_SUB_32 obj(Y, CO, A, B, SnA);

    initial
    begin
        #5 A = 0; B= 0; SnA = 0;
        #5 A = 0; B= 0; SnA = 1;
        #5 A = 0; B= 1; SnA = 0;
        #5 A = 0; B= 1; SnA = 1;
        #5 A = 1; B= 0; SnA = 0;
        #5 A = 1; B= 0; SnA = 1;
        #5 A = 1; B= 1; SnA = 0;
        #5 A = 1; B= 1; SnA = 1;
        #5;
    end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

The condition statements have `begin:` without a label. As is, the simulator is either treating it as a blank label or line-wrapping and making FULL_ADDER as the label name. Both are are illegal. Either add a label (preferred) or get rid of the colon.

FYI, the `if(i!=31 && i!=0)` is unnecessary as the conditions were caught in the prior conditions.

Example with labels:

```
if(i==0) 
begin: gen_first
    FULL_ADDER inst(.S(Y[i]), .CO(CO_TO_CI[i]), .A(A[i]), .B(XOR_OUT[i]), .CI(SnA));
end
else if(i==31) 
begin: gen_last
    FULL_ADDER inst(.S(Y[i]), .CO(CO), .A(A[i]), .B(XOR_OUT[i]), .CI(CO_TO_CI[i-1]));
end
else 
begin: gen_middle
    FULL_ADDER inst(.S(Y[i]), .CO(CO_TO_CI[i]), .A(A[i]), .B(XOR_OUT[i]), .CI(CO_TO_CI[i-1]));
end
```

Or without labels:

```
if(i==0) 
begin
    FULL_ADDER inst(.S(Y[i]), .CO(CO_TO_CI[i]), .A(A[i]), .B(XOR_OUT[i]), .CI(SnA));
end
else if(i==31) 
begin
    FULL_ADDER inst(.S(Y[i]), .CO(CO), .A(A[i]), .B(XOR_OUT[i]), .CI(CO_TO_CI[i-1]));
end
else 
begin
    FULL_ADDER inst(.S(Y[i]), .CO(CO_TO_CI[i]), .A(A[i]), .B(XOR_OUT[i]), .CI(CO_TO_CI[i-1]));
end
```